# Setting Highcharts color theme using CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

I am working on a dynamic theme setting for a dashboard including Highcharts.
The objective is to change the charts colors, based on the theme set for that specific user.

I have come up with a working solution for this, but this works only for localhost. Doesn't work if the CSS file sits on a remote server.

```
function getStyle(className) {
    var cssFileName = 'chart_theme_1.css';
    styleSheetsCount = document.styleSheets.length;
    for(j = 0; j < styleSheetsCount ; j++){
    var href = document.styleSheets[j].href;
    var a = href.split('/');
    if(a[a.length -1] == cssFileName){
        classes = document.styleSheets[j].rules || document.styleSheets[j].cssRules;
        break;
    }
    }

    for (var x = 0; x < classes.length; x++) {
        if (classes[x].selectorText == className) {
            return classes[x].style.color ; 
        }
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    colors =  [];    
    for (var i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
    colors.push(getStyle('.highChartsColor'+i));
    }
    Highcharts.setOptions({
        colors: colors,
        style: {
            fontFamily: 'Arial'
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Did you step through the debugger to see whether it gets the stylesheets properly?

Comment: Yes. When i checked using the debugger, the href  (of `document.stylesheet[j])` is correct. But, the `rules` and `cssRules` is set to `undefined`

Comment: could you a jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: In the highcharts you need to style elements by javascript, not CSS. See how to [define styles](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/design-and-style) for elements or [general theme](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/themes).

Answer (score 0):

Please be sure you are giving correct .css file path.

it may be: /var/www/html/<.folder name>/<.css file>

Please check your css file path.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?